# Viewing an object property's DebuggerDisplay

Tags: c#, debugging

Say I have the following two classes:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Test={Test}")]
class Class1
{
    public string Test;
}

[DebuggerDisplay("obj={obj}")]
class Class2
{
    public Class1 obj;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Class1() { Test = "test" };
        var c2 = new Class2() { obj = c1 };
    }
}
```

Is it possible to enable the debugger display of `Class2` to show the debugger display of `Class1`? I.e., I would like hovering over `c2` to reveal `obj="test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write in this style for your goal:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
class Class1
{
    public string Test;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Test=" + Test;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
class Class2
{
    public Class1 obj;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "obj=" + obj;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Class1() {Test = "test"};
        var c2 = new Class2() {obj = c1};
    }
}
```